# Why isn't my systemd service automatically starting?

Tags: systemd, yocto

Here is my boondocks-agent.service file. I have installed it in /lib/systemd/system:

```
[Unit]
Description=Boondocks agent
Requires=\
    balena.service 
After=\
    balena.service 

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
WatchdogSec=60
EnvironmentFile=/etc/boondocks-agent/agent.conf
EnvironmentFile=-/tmp/boondocks-agent.conf
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/stop-boondocks-agent
ExecStart=/usr/bin/healthdog --healthcheck=/usr/lib/boondocks-agent/boondocks-agent-healthcheck  /usr/bin/start-boondocks-agent
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/stop-boondocks-agent

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It doesn't appear to start up when I boot the system. After a clean boot, this is what I see for status:

```
systemctl status boondocks-agent
boondocks-agent.service - Boondocks agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/boondocks-agent.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

What do I have to do to make this start up automatically on boot?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz - apologies - the actual service file has the absolute path. The original question has the template I use to generate the file in a YOCTO build. I'll edit.

Comment: If this is a user-supplied unit, you really want to put it in `/etc/systemd/system`: the `/lib/systemd/system` directory [is for the distribution's use.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path) Although installers are good about not messing with foreign files, it's a risk that you don't have to take! Also, your `/etc/systemd/` files will override anything in `/lib/systemd/`, preventing potential issues in the future.

Comment: @ErikF - I think in this case, because I'm building the distribution using YOCTO, I _am_ the distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. I've gotten lazy and let my distros do all the grunt work for me! :-) I should really give it a shot; YOCTO looks really interesting.

Comment: @ErikF - YOCTO is great - once you get past the really really steep learning curve. :-)

Comment: Complementing the EDIT part in the question: From Yocto mega manual v2.4: > By default, the service is enabled to automatically start at boot
> time. The default setting is in the systemd class as follows:
> > SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE ??= "enable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable it a boot time:

`systemctl enable boondocks-agent`

Answer (score 8):

You say,

> In YOCTO, the equivalent to calling `systemctl enable` is:
>
> ```
>    SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = " \
>        boondocks-agent.service
>        "
> ```

I think this is the equivalent to *installing* the service. 
To have the service default to enabled you would want to add:

```
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable"
```

Comment: SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE is per-default true, if the recipe inherits the systemd class. Therefore it should not be required to set it explicitely to true. See https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I added a service and expected a timer to be start on boot. My timer was never started, but I could start it manually and have it run forever as expected. To get my Yocto project to create and start the timer I add to add

```
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = " logrotate.service logrotate.timer"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently when working on a Yocto project.
I had well specified in my Yocto recipe the following lines:

```
SYSTEMD_SERVICE:${PN} = "test.service"
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE:${PN} = "enable"
```

But, these were not effective until I realized that I had to make my recipe inheriting explicitly from systemd. This was done by adding the following line in my recipe

```
inherit systemd
```